# Complementary Maps

Tags: java, memory, dictionary

We have code with two complementary Maps like this:

```
private final Map<Integer, String> idToName = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
private final Map<String, Integer> nameToID = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
```

Whenever we put something in one, we also put in the other (with the key and value reversed) like this:

```
nameToID.put(name, id);
idToName.put(id, name);
```

We're running into a memory problem with this application.  It seems like there is a lot of duplication here.  Is there a way to make this more memory-efficient?  Some single structure that we could use?  I realize that this might be at the cost of time-efficiency, so I'm interested in what the trade-offs would be.

Comment: what are you using the two structures for? (other than the obvious of getting the id from the name and the name from the id)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what [Guava's](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`BiMap`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap) does, though there's only so much added memory efficiency you can get.  The biggest advantage of `BiMap` isn't so much memory efficiency as "it takes care of ensuring values are unique, and you can't forget to update the inverse map."

```
BiMap<Integer, String> idToName = HashBiMap.create();
idToName.put(1, "foo");
idToName.inverse(); // returns a BiMap mapping "foo" to 1
idToName.inverse().put("bar", 2); // idToName now has an extra mapping 2 -> "bar"
```

(Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Comment: Does it use 1/2 the space of the two complementary maps?  3/4 the space?

Comment: Depends which implementation...but usually, 1/1 the space.  There's not actually much room for improving memory efficiency; you can't "tangle" the hash maps.  Remember, though -- you're not storing the string twice; you're storing two references to the string, and references are very cheap.

Comment: (That said, future implementations might be improved -- yet another advantage of using a library.)

Comment: FYI: You made me think hard enough to figure out a way of making it happen.  https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/detail?r=72a25f66b25db2c957bf8f287c2e54baf418d514 saved ~38% on memory for HashBiMaps; that'll be part of the 14.0 release of Guava.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the BiMap class from Google Guava (docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html), however I don't know that it would be more memory efficient.

```
private final Map<Integer, String> idToName = new BiMap<Integer, String>();
private final Map<String, Integer> nameToID = idToName.inverse();
```

And you will only have to add to the `idToName` map:

```
idToName.put(name, id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use apache commons [**BidiMap**.](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html)

BidiMap exposes a method `inverseBidiMap()` which gets a view of this map where the keys and values are reversed.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Does it use less memory than two complementary maps?

Comment: Yes it would consume less memory than 2 maps